# flutter_webrtc : How to send text message to a peer during a visio

Tags: flutter, webrtc

In order to establish a visio between 2 peers, I developp an app for iOS and Android.
The language is flutter and I use the flutter_webrtc plugin from pub.dev.

Video and audio work fine using flutter-webrtc-server (https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc-server) as signaling server and another TURN server.

Now, I want to send data from peer 1 to peer 2. The data is a simple int, sent every second in order to synchronise counters.

I try to send data using  _socket.send(_encoder.convert(request)); (Signaling.dart), but if the type is not known ("peers", "offer", ...), the signaling server blocks my message (I set COUNTER as type) (Unknown type). It would have been a good solution...

Do you have any idea to send simple text message to another peer, or into a room, I don't care if other peers can read the messages !

Thanks,
Luc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it !
I added some code in singaler.go .
Very simple : copy the case "candidate" block and paste it just above. Then rename "candidate" into "counter".
So now, my signaling server relay the counter message. :-)